# "Message type 93 is not valid in the current context" while uploading via sftp: how to handle/continue?

Tags: c#, .net, sftp

Background: C#.net web application is transporting data over SFTP. The library used for file transport is Renci.SshNet.

One of my functionalities requires uploading a file from cloud storage to an SFTP server.

The code opens a write stream:

```
using System.IO;
using Renci.SshNet;

string address, port, login, password;
```

Retrieve address and port from selected settings, retrieve login and password from secret storage;

```
SftpClient fileLocation = new SftpClient(address, port, login, password);
string[] directories = Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Trim().Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
foreach(string directory in directories)
{
    fileLocation.ChangeDirectory(directory);
}
Stream outputStream = new StreamWriter(fileLocation.OpenWrite(fileName)).BaseStream;
```

At some point during writing to that stream (direct reading into that stream from another stream), the following exception is thrown:

```
Renci.SshNet.Common.SshException
Message type 93 is not valid in current context.
InnerException: null
HResult: -2146233088
TargetSite: Void WaitOnHandle(System.Threading.WaitHandle, System.TimeSpan)
```

I was not yet able to ascertain if this comes after a specific number of bytes, or a certain amount of time after beginning of transfer, or is random. The written file ends up incomplete. Using WinSCP, uploading files of the same and larger size works out just fine.

How can I properly make the process survive this error and complete the upload?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of the library (https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) there are recent changes.  It appears the error 93 is due to a window size change.  Not sure how that is related to posted code.  Maybe a remote sh is being opened and may have something to do with the WaitOnHandle error.  SFTP should not need a new shell so I'm suspecting it is an issue that was fixed in latest changes.

Comment: @jdweng That's SSH message window, not GUI window.

Comment: The error is a general windows 10 error.  The application is not meeting windows 10 guidelines.  If you convert number to hex you get 80131500.  That is why I recommended checking for updates.  One site says to make sure you driver are updated.So checking for Windows Updates and checking at Machine (mother board) website for updates is a good suggestion.

Comment: @jdweng No it's not. It's SSH  protocol problem. The server sends `SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_WINDOW_ADJUST` at a moment, when SSH.NET does not expect it. No Windows Update can help with that.

Comment: Where are you getting that info?

Comment: @jdweng It's clear from the error message and the source code. After all, even you have come to this conclusion initially (except for misunderstanding the meaning of *"window"*).

Comment: Isn't the message window a console window?  Lets stop arguing.  We are saying the same thing but you know more than I about the source.  The Renci.SshNet is a library and needs to be fixed.  My response of using latest is correct since the bug may already been fixed.  Since you know the solution to the problem than you should be fixing the library or giving info on how to fix.  Not making a comment that my answer is wrong.  Everything I said in this posting is accurate.

Comment: @jdweng I've only commented on the incorrect parts of your comments. It's not about console windows, it's about [protocol window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_window_protocol). And while SSH.NET update may indeed help, Windows update cannot help. – I do not know the solution. I just wanted to make sure that OP follows the right clues and not the wrong ones.

Comment: All you are doing is making comments to me and not talking directly to the OP.